# How to publish a folder of many react components created with create react app typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

I've been using the latest create react app with typescript for a large project, I have built many UI components in the `src/lib/` folder. Each component is then in its own folder with an index.tsx and a style.scss.

When I run `yarn build` the `/build` directory is made thanks to create react app. I can now browse the entire project which is great. But when I look inside `/build/static/` all the javascript is now in chunks.

In order to publish all the components to npm and reuse them in another project I need them to be kept in the same folder name and all the .scss to be converted to .css and all the .tsx to be converted to .js

The below is the standard tsconfig.json file

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "lib": [
     "dom",
     "dom.iterable",
     "esnext"
   ],
   "allowJs": true,
   "skipLibCheck": true,
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
   "strict": true,
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
   "module": "esnext",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "resolveJsonModule": true,
   "isolatedModules": true,
   "noEmit": true,
   "jsx": "react"
 },
 "include": [
   "src"
 ]
}
```

And the scripts from package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Ive tried installing `@babel/cli` and `@babel/preset-react` and made a .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["react-app"]
}
```

but then when I run 
`"compile": "NODE_ENV=production babel src --out-dir lib --extensions '.tsx, .scss'"` the .tsx files get copied and converted to js but the scss dont get converted to css.

Comment: Depending on your webpack config (if you use webpack), your CSS code may be injected in your HTML file. 

Give us more details on your bundler et its config please.

Comment: I just have babel installed and whatever `create react app` has under the hood

Answer (score 0):

You're using `create-react-app` which inject your CSS in the `index.html` file.

This library is not adequat to create a React composant library.
For this kind of project you may prefer [create-react-library](https://github.com/DimiMikadze/create-react-library), among others.